# Flexslider' CSS is not loaded on my Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flexslider

I am using the **Flexslider 2 Rails Gem** from https://github.com/constantm/Flexslider-2-Rails-Gem.

As informed in documentation, I called the JS and CSS, but only the CSS is not loaded (yes, JS works).

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin11.0]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.1
flexslider version: flexslider 2.2.0
```

**My app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require pineapple
*= require font-awesome
*= require dropzone/basic
*= require application/style
*= require fancybox
*= require flexslider.css
```

PS.: I tried *require flexslider* (without extension) too.

**My app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.slimscroll.min
//= require pineapple
//= require tinymce
//= require dropzone
//= require jquery-ui/sortable
//= require jquery-ui/effect-highlight
//= require jquery-ui/tooltip
//= require jquery.mjs.nestedSortable
//= require general
//= require maskedinput
//= require fancybox
//= require jquery.flexslider
```

**My HTML (I stripped others *li tags* here, but is the same)**

```
<div id="carousel0" class="flexslider carousel">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <%=link_to '/page/dynamic' do %>
            <%=image_tag image_path('show-case-1.jpg'), alt: 'Show Case', title: 'Show Case', class: 'img-responsive' %>
            <%end%>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My custom .JS**

```
$('#carousel0').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    itemWidth: 300,
    itemMargin: 100,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 8000
});
```

There are no console errors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom JS is loaded? Have you added console.log() statement to it?
If you don't see any errors on the console that leads me to think that the code is not triggered at all. Where is this custom JS code placed?
Test the code in the console. And check if the selector actually matches any elements.

Comment: Yes pascal betz, the JS works. The problem was: the CSS was in the wrong file. In many cases, call the css in application.css is right, but in my case, I have multiple sites in my application, that has specific JS and CSS to precompile. I call the css and js in this specific files instead application.(JS|CSS) and it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

My app has some "specific pages". The app has multiple sites independent each other.

In my *app/assets/stylesheets folder* and *app/assets/javascript folder* I have 1 more CSS and JS beyond the application.(JS|CSS)

There are sitetype.css AND sitetype.js.

I called *require flexslider.css* in *sitetype.css* AND *//= require jquery.flexslider* in *sitetype.js* and it works.

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`*= require flexslider.sass`

Shot in the dark after looking through the gem you're using

Comment: Well maybe not as I look at it more, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are only including the library and providing the markup. But you don't "Hook up the slider". See step 3 https://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: My fault, I forget to write this in my answer, but I "Hook up the slider" already. I am going update my answer with this data. I am trying rake assets:precompile now.